# Google Maps Android API Authorization Failure when reusing api access key in android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I created one application and generated an api key, which worked and my app correctly renders map.

I created a second application, which is based on an Android Library project I created and I want to reuse the API_KEY of the first app. In https://code.google.com/apis/console, for my API debug project, I selected "Edit allowed Android apps...".

Then on a new line, I added the SHA1 certificate fingerprint and package name (separated by a semicolon) of my second project. So now that API Access key has the fingerprints of two apps associated with it.

However, when I test the second app on my android phone, logcat outputs

> Google Maps Android API Authorization Failure.

The Certificate fingerprint of my second app is correct. My second app also references Google Play Services and is using Google API Level 16.

The second app manifest file is set up similarly to the first one, making reference to the debug API_KEY and having the same android permissions. What may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, the recommended practice is to sign each of your applications with a different certificate and get a different key for each one.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

:D

Comment: Very disappointing. I just found this out. They say you can use the same API key but I get the auth failure when I do. This creates clutter in the dev console, creating a new project for each app even though they are running from the same certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I've previously found this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/13865113/935779

> Make sure to export a signed copy with the same key you used to create your API key

This is often a problem when working with a Google Maps key and may very well be your issue. However, *Nathvi* is also correct from the documentation and you may consider a separate key if at all possible.